# UISegmentedControl Not Redrawn

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using a UISegmentedControl to show headers for a table view. When the orientation changes, the headers are resized depending on the labels in the table view underneath. Despite being connected up in IB, I have to move the phone around a bit to fire a `orientationChanged` notification and update the widths. I've even tried setting the first segment  width to 0 in IB, then again in viewDidLoad, but all headers are the same width when the view loads. I've tried using `performSelector:afterDelay` to make sure the view is actually on screen, and also calling `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay`, but nothing seems to work. I simply have to jiggle the phone around.

Is this a bug anyone has experience with or am I making a daft mistake?

I'm setting the width as below:

```
[segSortOrder setWidth:0.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  A screenshot might help.

Comment: The problem is the I need to use custom widths due to different 'column' widths in the UITableViewCells. When the view loads, until the method has been called a few times, or `performSelector:afterDelay` is used to dispatch the resize method later, all the segments in the SegmentedControl stay at their default widths, despite the widths being set in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I still think your question is just not clear enough to understand what you are trying to do.  You really need to attach a screenshot or wireframe is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came up with for this was to use `performSelector:afterDelay` and using `self.view.bounds.size.width` with a variable amount of padding (how much is trial and error for each ViewController. Not ideal but it does the job.